# populate gridview from bottom left

Tags: java, android, arrays, gridview

I'm looking for a way to populate a gridview from the bottom left going across and up rather than the top left going across and down, but also still be able to use pointToPosition(x, y) to get the correct element in the array (so bottom left would be 0).

I'm not entirely sure if this is possible or not but I guess it must be, however I can't think of any way to do it without messing up the ability to find the array indices properly. Any help would be appreciated.

here is the code to get the string array used to fill the grid:

```
        int num = 0;

        //populates a standard array from the grid in the JSONObject
        for (int vertical = 0; vertical < puzzleArray.size(); vertical++) //rows
        {
            for (int horizontal = 0; horizontal < puzzleArray.get(0).length(); horizontal++) //columns
            {
                //adds each letter of each row stored in puzzleArray to puzzleInputArray
                puzzleInputArray[num] = puzzleArray.get(vertical).charAt(horizontal) + "";

                num++;
            }
        }
```

The puzzleArray comes in as 9 strings of 9 letters which are then separated into a seperate array with the code above.

I fill the GridView with a standard ArrayAdapter:

```
            //fill GridView with the puzzle input array from the puzzle class
            ArrayAdapter<String> gridAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(c, R.layout.cell_layout, todaysPuzzle.puzzleInputArray);
            wordsearchGrid.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
```

And I need to be able to call the equivalent of this on the grid:

```
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
      downX = event.getX();
      downY = event.getY();

      startPosition = wordsearchGrid.pointToPosition((int)downX, (int)downY);
      letterDown = (String) wordsearchGrid.getItemAtPosition(startPosition);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to solve your problem, you simply have to use more advances techniques to create your adapter.

Writing an adapter in one line of code is great, but to get a more customized experience of *adapting* your array to a gridView, you will have to write a BaseAdapter yourself.

From there, it will be quite simple, you can for example have two arrays as its member variables, one to store the "real" indexes, and one to the "displaying" indexes.

Hope I helped you :) !

Comment: I'm pretty new to Android coding so I've never made a custom adapter before, do you know of any decent guides to help me get my head around it?